# Jmeter - running GUI test from terminal

Tags: terminal, jmeter, web-api-testing

I'm trying to run Jmeter GUI test from terminal (in MAC). instead of running the GUI tests (that work when running from GUI), it created another folder next the existing one - named without underscore. my tests folder is 'Jmeter_Tests' and the terminal run creates 'Jmeter Tests'
the command (running from jmeter bin directory):

```
./jmeter -n -t /Users/myusername/Jmeter_Tests/SB1.jmx
```

could the terminal command run the GUI test?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to execute a command line statement to open JMeter GUI mode and then immediately start a test.  (Please correct me if that was not your question!)

In most cases you want to run non-gui for real test execution anyway.  When using terminal to start a .jmx test plan you must pass the following flags:

```
%JMETER_HOME%/jmeter -n -t /path/to/test_plan.jmx -l /path/to/desired/output.jtl
```

Its also suggested to use this as well:

```
-j /path/to/desired/jmeter_log.txt
```

For more details, visit this page: [JMeter Getting Started - GUI Mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

Edit:  To get nice data analysis of a JTL file after a non-gui test run, check out CMDRunner.jar from the JMeter Plugins packages: [CMDRunner Man Pages](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)